# How to render a cross as a highcharts marker?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to extend highcharts to include a cross symbol. My svg path is rendering a triangle and I'm not sure why.

Since `highcharts` does not accept actual svg paths, this task is more challenging than rendering a horizontal line and a vertical line.

The path I have should do this :

1. Start at top middle
2. line to bottom middle
3. line to center
4. line to left middle

   ```
   $.extend(Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols,
   {       
       Cross: function (x, y, w, h) 
       { 
       var trianglesArray = [];

       trianglesArray.push('M');
       trianglesArray.push(x + (w * .5));
       trianglesArray.push(y);

       trianglesArray.push('L');
       trianglesArray.push(x + (w * .5));
       trianglesArray.push(y + h);

       trianglesArray.push('L');
       trianglesArray.push(x + (w * .5));
       trianglesArray.push(y + (h * .5));

       trianglesArray.push('L');
       trianglesArray.push(x);
       trianglesArray.push(y + (h * .5));

       trianglesArray.push('L');
       trianglesArray.push(x + w);
       trianglesArray.push(y + (h * .5));

       trianglesArray.push('z');

       return trianglesArray;
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepare cross as image and then use it as symbol like in the example with other image:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/

```
 marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                }
```

Comment: The reason I am using svg's to extend the symbols collection is so that I can get scale and color.